# Как проверить выполняеться ли в данный момент определенная программа в Windows?

Tags: windows, bat, task

OC: Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise 64 bit

Могу вызвать tasklist в консоли и визуально определить. Как можно проверить выполняеться ли task с помошью bat кода?

Comment: `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq modulename.exe"` - и делай с результатом всё, что надо.

Comment: Спасибо. Да он показывает теперь только один процесс. Каким образом я могу теперь получить однозначный ответ в структуре "if"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
if '%1'=='' goto usage
for /F %%a in ('tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq %1"') do if %%a==%1 goto exist
echo Module %1 not found in processlist.
goto done
:usage
echo USAGE: %0 modulename.ext
goto done
:exist
echo Module %1 is running.
:done
```